# Google sheet to Html Json Data - On Click Show New Box Show Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to fetch data from the google sheet, through JSON format and show in HTML. which is fine.

What I want, onclick on items or arrow
[image]

Open the sidebar and fetch relative data of item with list like

1. Slip No : 1207
2. Client Name: Client
3. Email : exmple2@gmail.com
4. Delivery : Next Sunday

Like Whatsapp look at people's details onclick

[image]

```js
   $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XaFRnQfNPRP86UPNcdgQuCCH6AeVe5FZOxBHaIPZDpM/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {

            var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

                var name = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$slipno']['$t'];
                var id = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$id']['$t'];
                var clientname = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$clientname']['$t'];

                // var email = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$email']['$t'];
                // var delivery = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$delivery']['$t'];

                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML +=
                    ('<tr class="dd d-flex justify-content-around">' +
                        '<td>' +
                        " <span id='" + 't' + id + "'>" + name + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="cn">' + clientname + '</span>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="ml-auto gg">' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
            }
        });
```

```css
      tbody>tr>td>span {
                    text-align: left;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .dd {
                    border-bottom: rgb(202, 202, 202) solid 1px;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .cn {
                    font-weight: 700;
                }
                
                .gg::before {
                    content: ">";
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> brand</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav  mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container text-center my-4">

        <!-- Table  -->
        <table class="table " id="testTable">
            <!-- Table head -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Google Sheet Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table head -->
        
            <!-- Table body -->
            <tbody id="demo">


            </tbody>
            <!-- Table body -->
        </table>
        <!-- Table  -->

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a global array called `myData.` When the service is called, the array is reset and records are added. Each record is built to contain the data that you want to work with. The index is saved to the record so it can be used to find the record in `myData` when an element is selected.

I decided to add `onclick` methods to the elements you want to use to show the details, which is `clientname` and the arrow icon. Clicking an element passes the index that is tied to the record and is used to reference the data in `myData.`

```js
var myData = [];

// an example function that will get the data by index so it can be used however you want
function showDetails(index) {
   var selectedData = myData[index];
   alert(JSON.stringify(selectedData, null, 2));
}

$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XaFRnQfNPRP86UPNcdgQuCCH6AeVe5FZOxBHaIPZDpM/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {

            myData = []; // reset whenever data loads
            var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

                var dataPoint = {
                  name: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$slipno']['$t'],
                  id: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$id']['$t'],
                  clientname: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$clientname']['$t'],
                  delivery: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$delivery']['$t']
                };
                myData.push(dataPoint); // add data point to array to reference later

                // var email = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$email']['$t'];
                // var delivery = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$delivery']['$t'];

                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML +=
                    ('<tr class="dd d-flex justify-content-around">' +
                        '<td>' +
                        " <span id='" + 't' + dataPoint.id + "'>" + dataPoint.name + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="cn" onclick="showDetails(' + i + ');">' + dataPoint.clientname + '</span>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="ml-auto gg" onclick="showDetails(' + i + ');">' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
            }
        });
```

```css
tbody>tr>td>span {
                    text-align: left;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .dd {
                    border-bottom: rgb(202, 202, 202) solid 1px;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .cn {
                    font-weight: 700;
                }
                
                .gg::before {
                    content: ">";
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> brand</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav  mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container text-center my-4">

        <!-- Table  -->
        <table class="table " id="testTable">
            <!-- Table head -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Google Sheet Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table head -->
        
            <!-- Table body -->
            <tbody id="demo">


            </tbody>
            <!-- Table body -->
        </table>
        <!-- Table  -->

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you JSON.stringify, Just print in <p id="listData"></p>

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I used `JSON.stringify` to print the data in an easily digestible format in the alert dialog. You can certainly "print" this data to any element on the page or in a new element added to the page if that's your goal.

Comment: onclick on arrow. Show data in <p id="slipno"></p> | <p id="clientname"></p> | <p id="delivery"></p>